# Module order in Outlook is different than browser

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2010

[image: ie Module][image: outlook module]

As you can see from screen shot, the display order of modules is different  in outlook 2010 than browser. I want the outlook also to display modules in same order as shown in browser. In outlook Business is on top but in browser its in 2 place. I used pragma toolkit to change the order of module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the navigation areas in the SiteMap.

[From the SDK:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309259.aspx) (My emphasis):

The following diagram shows the Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook navigation. **Microsoft Outlook presents each navigation area in alphabetical order in a tree view instead of using the order specified in the SiteMap**. Each person can choose to position the reading pane at the bottom as shown or on the side. They can also choose not to show it. Each entity can be configured to determine whether it will display the reading pane...

If you really need it to be a specific order, you could perhaps prefix each navigation section with a number. A bit of an ugly solution but I'm not sure there is any other option.